# Rewriting nginx's try_files

Tags: nginx

I am trying to convert a very simple rewrite from a previous nginx version to the current one looking like below:

```
location / {
   if ( !-f $request_filename ) {
     rewrite ^/([a-z]*)$ /index.php?action=$1;
     rewrite ^/([a-z]*)/(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1&item=$2;
   }
}
```

This is how far I have gotten. The index page shows up, but any page that should be rewritten like above, instead throws 404's:

```
server {

    listen 80 default;
    root /var/www;
    index index.php;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?action=$uri&item=$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's happening exactly? Part of the problem is $uri and $args are not properly encoded.

Comment: 404 is thrown with `File not found. ` if I use either URI `/page` or `/page/id`

Comment: What happens when you do just `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php`?

Comment: Index.php works nicely, but anything that should be rewritten ends up in 404's

Comment: Try `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args`. You should be able to get the URL with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. $_GET should work normally.

Comment: No change. `$_GET` probably works as I can access `/index.php?action=projects&item=1` but both `/projects` & `/projects/1` still equals to 404 as intended in the application

Comment: Can you provide more of the config in your question? Specifically the PHP-FPM/FastCGI parts.

Comment: @Luke Updated my question with the complete config. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rules; 
} 

location @rules { 
    rewrite ^/([a-z]*)$ /index.php?action=$1; 
    rewrite ^/([a-z]*)/(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1&item=$2; 
}

location /index.php { 
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; 
    include fastcgi_params; 
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
}
```

Comment: Hmm. In your first example, index.php will load, but any static files or URI requests such as `/page1/item` will return the index.php

Comment: That's odd. try_files should be taking care of that.

Comment: Tried the second example as well. Same issue there

Comment: I'm assuming `try_files $uri $uri/` works with static files?

Comment: Yep. Restarted server and second example began to work, all except for the $_GET-based routing. Anything passed after `/` results in the `index.php` loading front page with URI arguments stripped out (GET `/projects` => GET `/`)

Comment: For the second one, try `try_files $uri $uri/ @php?$args`. Not sure if that'll work. It should have worked normally.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5855/discussion-between-luke-and-industrial)